# How do I remove blank lines from text in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove blank lines (with whitespace or absolutely blank) in PHP. I use this regular expression, but it does not work:

```
$str = ereg_replace('^[ \t]*$\r?\n', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('^[ \t]*$\r?\n', '', $str);
```

I want a result of:

```
blahblah

blahblah

   adsa 


sad asdasd
```

will:

```
blahblah
blahblah
   adsa 
sad asdasd
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
// New line is required to split non-blank lines
preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string);
```

The above regular expression says:

```
/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/
    1st Capturing group (^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)
        1st Alternative: ^[\r\n]*
        ^ assert position at start of the string
            [\r\n]* match a single character present in the list below
                Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                \r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
                \n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
        2nd Alternative: [\r\n]+
            [\r\n]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
            \n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
    [\s\t]* match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        \tTab (ASCII 9)
    [\r\n]+ match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
        \n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
```

Comment: This is also found here: http://programming-oneliners.blogspot.com/2006/03/remove-blank-empty-lines-php-29.html

Comment: return preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string); this work

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the regex does? I don't like using code that I don't know anything about.

Comment: I agree with the sol'n from @StoneHeart but with slight changes. Thus: `preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", PHP_EOL, $string)`. Using `PHP_EOL` then on would allow you to have a consistent line breaking character that the interpreter really understands.

Answer (score 30):

Your `ereg-replace()` solution is wrong because the `ereg/eregi` methods are deprecated.  Your `preg_replace()` won't even compile, but if you add delimiters and set multiline mode, it will work fine:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^[ \t]*[\r\n]+/m', '', $str);
```

The `m` modifier allows `^` to match the beginning of a logical line rather than just the beginning of the whole string.  The start-of-line anchor is necessary because without it the regex would match the newline at the end of every line, not just the blank ones.  You don't need the end-of-line anchor (`$`) because you're actively matching the newline characters, but it doesn't hurt.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/709684/20938) gets the job done, but it's more complicated than it needs to be.  The regex has to match either the beginning of the string (`^[\r\n]*`, multiline mode not set) or at least one newline (`[\r\n]+`), followed by at least one newline (`[\r\n]+`).  So, in the special case of a string that starts with one or more blank lines, they'll be replaced with *one* blank line. I'm pretty sure that's not the desired outcome.

But most of the time it replaces two or more consecutive newlines, along with any horizontal whitespace (spaces or tabs) that lies between them, with one linefeed.  That's the intent, anyway. The author seems to expect `\s` to match just the space character (`\x20`), when in fact it matches any whitespace character.  That's a very common mistake.  The actual list varies from one regex flavor to the next, but at minimum you can expect `\s` to match whatever `[ \t\f\r\n]` matches.

Actually, in PHP you have a better option:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\h*\v+/m', '', $str);
```

`\h` matches any horizontal whitespace character, and `\v` matches vertical whitespace.

Comment: In addition to above solution (which works perfectly), here one more. The difference to the other is, it preserves 1 empty line and removes only if there are 2 or more:

**$content = preg_replace('/^\h+\v+/m', '', $content);**

Answer (score 18):

Just explode the lines of the text to an array, remove empty lines using `array_filter` and implode the array again.

```
$tmp = explode("\n", $str);
$tmp = array_filter($tmp);
$str = implode("\n", $tmp);
```

Or in one line:

```
$str = implode("\n", array_filter(explode("\n", $str)));
```

I don't know, but this is maybe faster than `preg_replace`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Ben, this wouldn't work because you explode "n" number of "\n" and then what you do is add the same number of "\n" and rebuild the same string.

Comment: Did you actually try it? `array_filter()` removes the _blank_ elements of the array created using `explode()`.

Comment: The other solutions are one-liner. I feel like they are better, maybe faster. But at the end, I ended up using Ben's solution. It's so much more clear. Quite often, maintainability is more important that saving a few milliseconds... One difference, I used `preg_split('/\R/', $str);` instead of explode, to make sure it works with text formatted with any form of newline (\n, \r, \r\n).

Comment: A slight variation on this answer would be to use `trim()` as the filter callback, to take advantage of its ["whitespace" definitions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), eg: `$str = implode("\n", array_filter(explode("\n", $str), "trim"));`

Answer (score 9):

The [comment from Bythos](http://programming-oneliners.blogspot.com.au/2006/03/remove-blank-empty-lines-php-29.html?showComment=1258967786143#c1573838206820839972) from Jamie's link above worked for me:

```
/^\n+|^[\t\s]*\n+/m
```

I didn't want to strip all of the new lines, just the empty/whitespace ones. This does the trick!

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to overcomplicate things. This can be achieved with a simple short regular expression:

```php
$text = preg_replace("/(\R){2,}/", "$1", $text);
```

The `(\R)` matches all newlines. 
The `{2,}` matches two or more occurrences. 
The `$1` Uses the first backreference (platform specific EOL) as the replacement.

Comment: Just some remarks: a) `\R` is not platform specific EOL (it just matches different EOL sequences) ; b) the pattern won't mangle empty lines (those with whitespace). To not overcomplicate including preserving the EOL sequences see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68873784 and compare with the pattern, replacement `'/\s*($|\R)/'`, `'\1'`.

Answer (score 5):

This has been already answered long time ago but can greatly benefit for `preg_replace` and a much simplified pattern:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\s*($|\n)/', '\1', $subject);
```

*Pattern: Remove all white-space before a new-line -or- at the end of the string.*

Longest match wins:

- As the white-space `\s` has a greedy quantifier `*` and contains `\n` consecutive empty lines are matched.
- As `\s` contains `\r` as well, `\r\n` new-line sequences are supported, however single `\r` (without `\n`) are not.
- And when `$` matches the end of the buffer the backreference `\1` is empty allowing to handle trailing whitespace at the very end, too.

If leading (empty) lines need to be removed as well, they have to match while not capturing, too (this was not directly asked for but could be appropriate):

```
$result = preg_replace('/^(?:\s*\n)+|\s*($|\n)/', '\1', $subject);
#                        '----------'
```

*Pattern: Also remove all leading white-space (first line(s) are empty).*

And if the new-line at the end of the buffer should be normalized differently (always a newline at the end instead of never), it needs to be added: `. "\n"`.

This variant is portable to `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n` new-line sequences (`(?>\r\n|\r|\n)`) or `\R`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^(?> |\t|\r\n|\r|\n)+|(?> |\t|\r\n|\r|\n)*($|(?>\r\n|\r|\n))/', '\1', $subject);
# or:
$result = preg_replace('/^(?:\s*\R)+|\s*($|\R)/', '\1', $subject);
```

*Pattern: Support all new-line sequences.*

This is with the downside that the new-lines can not be normalized (e.g. any of the three to `\n`).

Therefore, it can make sense to normalize new-lines before removing:

```
$result = preg_replace(['/(?>\r\n|\n|\r)/', '/\s*($|\n)/'], ["\n", '\1'], $subject);
# or:
$result = preg_replace(['/\R/u', '/\s*($|\n)/'], ["\n", '\1'], $subject);
```

It ships with the opportunity to do some normalization apart from the line handling.

For example removal of the trailing white-space and fixing the missing new-line at the end of file.

Then doing more advanced line normalization, for example zero empty lines at the beginning and end; otherwise not more than two consecutive empty lines:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    ['/[ \t]*($|\R)/u', '/^\n*|(\n)\n*$|(\n{3})\n+/'], 
    ["\n"             , '\1\2'                      ], 
    $subject
);
```

*The secondary pattern benefits from the first patterns replacements already.*

The power with `preg_replace` relies here in choosing the backreference(s) to replace with wisely.

Also using multiple patterns can greatly simplify things and keep the process maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

The idea: match all white-space sequence greedily and let the regex engine backtrack if needed until an end of line.

```
$str = preg_replace('~(*ANY)\A\s*\R|\s*(?!\r\n)\s$~mu', '', $str);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/f0cB4#v8.2.11)

---

**Pattern details:**

The pattern uses 2 modifiers:

- **m** (multiline modifier): `^` and `$` matches respectively the start and the end of a line.
- **u** (unicode modifier): extends the character classes to unicode (`\s` here) and read the subject string as a UTF-8 string. The alias `\R` is also extended and set to `(*BSR_UNICODE)`.

In addition to the **m** modifier, the pattern starts with `(*ANY)` that defines the newline convention. In other words `$` will succeed at each position with a newline sequence or at the end of the string.

The alias `\R`, in this PCRE2_BSR_UNICODE mode, matches the following newline sequences:

- `\r\n` (carriage return + newline)
- `\n` (new line)
- `\x0b` (vertical tab)
- `\f` (form feed)
- `\r` (carriage return)
- `\N{U+0085}` (NEL)
- `\N{U+2028}` (line separator)
- `\N{U+2029}` (paragraph separator)

So don't hesitate to replace `\R` with `(?>\r\n|\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\N{U+0085}|\N{U+2028}|\N{U+2029})` if you want to impress your mother-in-law.

The first alternative `\A\s*\R` is only here for leading blank lines. `\A` matches the start of the string.

The second alternative `\s*(?!\r\n)\s$` matches greedily any white-space sequence until an end of line, but since `$` matches at the newline sequence position, the newline sequence isn't a part of the match result and is preserved. `(?!\r\n)\s` is only here to avoid an eventual sequence `\r\n` to be cut.

---

**Pro:**

- It works with any unicode newline sequence and do not change it.
- It removes as well leading and trailing blank lines.
- It removes also blank lines that eventually contains a space or any other white character.

**Cons:**

- It right-trims each line, that may be an unwanted behavior (but most of the time it is more a benefit).

---

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\s+\r?\n$/D', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\r\n", $str);
```

If you output this to a text file, it will give the same output in the simple [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29), [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad) and also in text editors, for example [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B).

Comment: This is 99.9% the same answer as the selected answer. Maybe you could try something unique that would actually contribute to the original question. You're not explaining what does the regex do!

Answer (score 0):

```
function trimblanklines($str) {
    return preg_replace('`\A[ \t]*\r?\n|\r?\n[ \t]*\Z`','',$str);
}
```

This one only removes them from the beginning and end, not the middle (if anyone else was looking for this).

Comment: Shouldn't we be using `trim($str);` It does the trick for your answer!

Comment: @bantya That's not at all the same. My function removes leading and trailing entirely blank/whitespace *lines*, like from a paragraph of text. If the 1st line is blank and the 2nd line is indented, those whitespaces won't be touched even though they're at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer leaves an extra line-break at the end of the string. Using `rtrim()` will remove this final linebreak:

```
rtrim(preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575992/using-php-to-minify-javascript-html-css-within-a-string?answertab=votes#tab-top), the following works fine for me!

```
$str = "<html>
<body>";

echo str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    function del_blanklines_in_array_q($ar){
        $strip = array();
        foreach($ar as $k => $v){
            $ll = strlen($v);
            while($ll--){
                if(ord($v[$ll]) > 32){  //hex /0x20 int 32 ascii SPACE
                    $strip[] = $v; break; 
                }
            }
        }
        return $strip;
    }

    function del_blanklines_in_file_q($in, $out){
        // in filename, out filename
        $strip = del_blanklines_in_array_q(file($in));
        file_put_contents($out, $strip );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "file_name.txt";
$file_data = file_get_contents($file);
$file_data_after_remove_blank_line = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $file_data );
file_put_contents($file,$file_data_after_remove_blank_line);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/[\n\r?]{2,}/m", "\n", $text);
```

Answer (score -1):

nl2br(preg_replace('/^\v+/m', '', $r_msg))

Comment: Why do you want to add `<br>` to the result?