# Remove trailing lines with php preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, eol

I know this has been asked before @ [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709669/how-do-i-remove-blank-lines-from-text-in-php), but I am trying to strip empty lines at the end as well.

I am using:

```
function removeEmptyLines($string)
{
return preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string);
}
```

Which works great in any combination but:

```
 aadasdadadsad
 adsadasdasdas
 (empty line here)
```

I'm attempting to do a count() on the returned array, but since it is replacing the `\n` with a `\n\`, it's not working. I tried a few other examples in the above post, but none have worked.

My other function (so far)

```
function checkEmails($value) {

$value = removeEmptyLines($value);

$data = explode("\n", $value);
$count = count($data);

return $count;

 }
```

Basically it's a form's text-area posting to itself and if someone hits enter after the a full line, it still counts the blank line.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Tre

Comment: aren't you trying to invent an equivalent of ltrim function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_replace('/^[\r\n]+|[\r\n]+$/m', '', $string);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/xR3ie8me)

If you want to strip leading/trailing whitespace from the lines as well, replace the two occurences of `[\r\n]` with `\s`. Note also that the fact I have single-quoted the expression string is important.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [trim](http://www.php.net/trim) function does this by default:

```
$string = trim($string);
```

You can also use either `ltrim()` or `rtrim()` if you only want to strip from the start or end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use

```
rtrim($string, "\n");
```

Comment: You can't single quote \n, so this will only work if you double quote it instead. And the code in the question is stripping more chars than just \n