# Using PHP to minify JavaScript, HTML, and CSS WITHIN A STRING

Tags: php, minify

All of the PHP minify functions I've seen have dealt with physical JavaScript, HTML, CSS files. I would like a function that, when given something like this:

```
$code = "<html>
    <body>";
```

Will minify it to one line. I am not looking for something like the [YUI Compressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUI_Library#Build_tools), as that deals with files on a server. I would simply like a function that minifies a string passed to it. Does this exist anywhere?

Comment: You should be able to mock a file using the SPL. Put the string into the file. Pass it the the known minify functions.

Comment: That sounds pretty inefficient though.  Is there a straight-up function that does it?

Comment: Maybe, Maybe not. The SPL has a mock file, that you can put n memory. I'm not sure how inefficient it is.  see; http://www.php.net/manual/en/spltempfileobject.construct.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be looking for:

```
$code = "<html>
    <body>";

echo str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $code);
```

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a complete minification function, so you could pass, say, the front-end source code for Google to it.

Comment: And it would do what? Fetch all the assets (e.g. external JS/CSS/images etc) and inline/minify them? What are you trying to do? https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module might be a good tool to solve whatever it is you are doing?

Comment: I simply would like to have a function that minifies a STRING of HTML/CSS/JS, not a FILE

Comment: How is it any different? The code will read the file into a string, minify the string, then write back to the file. https://github.com/mrclay/minify/tree/master/min/lib is the code for PHP Minify - you'll see the functions needed in there.

Comment: So I would use fwrite, etc. to write the file, then open it and pass it into that function?

Comment: You could, or just call the functions on a string – minify($html, $options = array()) is in https://github.com/mrclay/minify/blob/master/min/lib/Minify/HTML.php.

Comment: Ah, so if I passed the HTML/JS/CSS string to that function, it would return me with a string?

Comment: I actually ended up using the JSMin.php file; thanks for the help!

Comment: So bad way, this will break inline js

Answer (score 0):

I never tried these ones, but I came across them once:

For JavaScript and CSS:

http://castlesblog.com/2010/august/14/php-javascript-css-minification

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is for external files, not strings.

Comment: The link is broken: *"It looks like the page your are looking for is missing. Please check the address or try another page."*

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```php
$out = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/page.html');
$replace = ["\r", "\t", "\n"];
for ($i = 2; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    $replace[] = str_repeat(' ', $i);
}
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/page.html', str_replace($replace, '', $out));
```

and more easy with regex

```php
$out = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/page.html');
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/output.html', preg_replace("/(\s{2,}|\t|\r|\n)/i",'',$out));
```