# PHP strip_tags except certain characters

Tags: php, html

I am using `strip_tags` in PHP to remove HTML tags when echoing data.

My string looks like:

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Test 1, Test2<br>
Test 3,<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Test 4<br>
Test 5<br>
<br>
Test 6 test 7
```

How can I remove the `<br>` tags that leave big gaps but keep the `<br>` tags between line gaps (like that between `Test 1, Test2<br>Test3`)?

And just remove the:

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

So the string will end up looking like:

```
Test 1, Test2<br>
Test 3,<br>
Test 4<br>
Test 5<br>
<br>
Test 6 test 7
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: So, if your trying to replace _n_ `<br>`s, where _n_ is any number greater than one, with one `<br>`, regex replace will work great.

Comment: Sorry, but in the string you posted there is no ´<br>´ tag between Test2 and Test3. So your goal is _not_ to keep such tags, but to _add_ them? I suggest you remove all tags and afterwards replace the linebreaks (which are still present) by `<br>` tags using phps `nl2br()` function.

Comment: A hint, I'm lazy atm: `foreach($DOMXPath->query('//br/preceding-sibling::br') as $br){$br->parentNode->removeChild($br);}`.

Comment: check my updated questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably cleaner to do this in two steps:

```
// remove <br> tags
$text = preg_replace('#^(<br[\\s]*(>|\/>)\s*){2,}$#im', '', $text);

// remove empty lines - from http://stackoverflow.com/a/709684/
$text = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", PHP_EOL, $text);
```

---

**Explanation - `#^(<br\s*(>|\/>)\s*){2,}$#im`**

- `^` - beginning of the line anchor
- `(` - first capturing group

  - `<br` - literal characters `<`, followed by `b`, followed by `r`
  - `\s*` - any whitespace character, zero or more times
  - `(>|\/>)` - alternation - match both `<br>` and `<br/>`
  - `\s*` - followed by optional whitespace
- `)` - end of first capturing group
- `{2,}` - match the previous group, 2 or more times
- `i` - match both cases
- [`m`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) - make the pattern match lines separately

Output:

```
Test 1, Test2<br>
Test 3,<br>Test 4<br>
Test 5<br>
<br>
Test 6 test 7
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/100216)