# PHP ignore new lines that are blank characters when using nl2br

Tags: php, string, nl2br

If the new line contains only blank characters or is an empty string, how can it be ignored when using nl2br?

Comment: That would defeat pretty much the whole purpose of nl2br?

Comment: @Fluffeh It appears that way to me but if a user adds a space between two lines of text, nl2br will double that space when echoed out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709669/how-do-i-remove-blank-lines-from-text-in-php

Answer (score 0):

replace 2 or more continues \n and empty lines for only one \n

```
<?php
$text = "Hello
[tab]
[spaces]
      world

";
echo nl2br(preg_replace("/\W+\n+/", "\n", $text));
```

return

```
Hello<br />
world<br />
```