# PHP remove black new lines

Tags: php

I have got this php code

```
    $Text=htmlspecialchars($_POST['new_post'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $Text=trim($Text);
```

`Text` is variable that is defined by user.If `text` is

```
There is a pleasure in the pathless woods,
There is a rapture on the lonely shore,
There is society, where none intrudes.
```

I want it to stay like that.But if `Text` is

```
By the deep Sea, and music in its roar:


I love not Man the less, but Nature more,



From these our interviews, in which I steal
```

I want it to be

```
By the deep Sea, and music in its roar:
I love not Man the less, but Nature more,
From these our interviews, in which I steal
```

How can i achieve that with PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove blank lines from text in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709669/how-do-i-remove-blank-lines-from-text-in-php)

Comment: I did that but it did not work.@Script47

Comment: show us your html output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). This will find any multiple lines, and replace them with a single new line:

```
$Text = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $Text);
```

See a demo [here](https://3v4l.org/VuVFq):

```
$Text = "There is a pleasure in the pathless woods,


There is a rapture on the lonely shore,


There is society, where none intrudes.";


$Text=trim($Text);
$Text=preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $Text);

echo $Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use str_replace for this

```
str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $text);
```

Also any reason you're escaping on input rather than output?

Comment: I am inserting it into db thats why.And it did no difference

Comment: You should escape (to prevent XSS attacks) on output not input

Comment: Won't it take more memory in database? @Marktwigg

Comment: no, if anything it will use more memory because most HTML entities use more bytes than the original HTML its self