# How to remove empty lines in php email

Tags: php, email

I have a php form that when posted sends a confirmation email. The form has several drop downs that when populated, displays a quantity and name of a part. I have everything working correctly, in my $usermessage, I have listed all of the variables that corresponds to the drop downs. I only want to display the drop downs and names that have been populated, which I have achieved. I cannot figure out how to remove the extra spaces for when a variable is not populated.

My confirmation email looks like this when I have the first two drop downs and the 8th one populated:

*Users Information

Name

John Doe


Email address

email@email.com


Address

12345 street


US

Town State Zip


Phone Number

1234567890


Qty

Item #


2

CH171181


1

CH171182










1

CH171363*

As you can see, there is a huge gap of space compensating for the unpopulated variables.

Here is my code:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$myemail ="$email"; 

$CH171181 = $_POST["CH171181"];
$CH171182 = $_POST["CH171182"];
$CH171183 = $_POST["CH171183"];
$CH171184 = $_POST["CH171184"]; 
$CH171360 = $_POST["CH171360"]; 
$CH171361 = $_POST["CH171361"];
$CH171362 = $_POST["CH171362"]; 
$CH171363 = $_POST["CH171363"]; 
$CH171364 = $_POST["CH171364"]; 
$CH171404 = $_POST["CH171404"];     
$CH171408 = $_POST["CH171408"];
if ( empty($CH171181) ) {$var1 = '';} else {$var1 = 'CH171181';}
if ( empty($CH171182) ) {$var2 = '';} else {$var2 = 'CH171182';}
if ( empty($CH171183) ) {$var3 = '';} else {$var3 = 'CH171183';}
if ( empty($CH171184) ) {$var4 = '';} else {$var4 = 'CH171184';}
if ( empty($CH171360) ) {$var5 = '';} else {$var5 = 'CH171360';}
if ( empty($CH171361) ) {$var6 = '';} else {$var6 = 'CH171361';}
if ( empty($CH171362) ) {$var7 = '';} else {$var7 = 'CH171362';}
if ( empty($CH171363) ) {$var8 = '';} else {$var8 = 'CH171363';}
if ( empty($CH171364) ) {$var9 = '';} else {$var9 = 'CH171364';}
if ( empty($CH171404) ) {$var10 = '';} else {$var10 = 'CH171404';}
if ( empty($CH171408) ) {$var11 = '';} else {$var11 = 'CH171408';}

$first_name = $_POST["first_name"]; 
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];   
$address = $_POST["address"];
$address2 = $_POST["address2"]; 
$country = $_POST["country"];   
$city = $_POST["city"]; 
$state = $_POST["state"];   
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];   

$user = "$myemail";
$usersubject = "Subject";
$userheaders = "From: support@support.com\n";
$usermessage = "

Users Information
Name
$first_name $last_name

Email address
$email

Address
$address
$address2
$country
$city $state $zip

Phone Number
$phone

Qty
Item #

$CH171181
$var1

$CH171182
$var2

$CH171183
$var3

$CH171184
$var4

$CH171360
$var5

$CH171361
$var6

$CH171362
$var7

$CH171363
$var8

$CH171364
$var9

$CH171404
$var10

$CH171408
$var11
";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";    

mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders,$headers);
}
```

Comment: Could also use preg_replace to drop white space

Comment: Show us the code that builds the actual email contents from those variables

Comment: Visit this Issue You will find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709669/how-do-i-remove-blank-lines-from-text-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the output within 1 continuous string you need to do a check to see whether the variable contains a string. If it's empty then don't even include it in `$usermessage`.

For example:

```
if ($CH171183 !== ''):
    $usermessage .= $CH171183 . "\n" . $var3;
endif;
```

This means that if `$CH171183` contains a string, it will be included in the output (`$usermessage`). But if it doesn't - nothing including the spaces where that would otherwise go - will appear in the output. In other words, you're only creating output where you *do* have data to show.

The issue with your original code is that `$usermessage` has no checks to say whether a variable is empty or not. So if it is empty, you just end up with empty spaces in the output.

Comment: This did it, I removed all of the listed variables after 'Item #' and then put this code at the end after the closing semicolon for $usermessage. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str_replace(chr(13), "", $usermessage)
```

Comment: That'll work but it's not really tackling the source of the problem, which is he's outputting variables which may be set to an empty string or null. It's like creating a problem, then fixing it retrospectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of the code below:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$myemail ="$email"; 

$vars = Array("CH171181",
              "CH171182",
              "CH171183",
              "CH171184",
              ... etc
        );

$first_name = $_POST["first_name"]; 
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];   
$address = $_POST["address"];
$address2 = $_POST["address2"]; 
$country = $_POST["country"];   
$city = $_POST["city"]; 
$state = $_POST["state"];   
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];   

$user = "$myemail";
$usersubject = "Subject";
$userheaders = "From: support@support.com\n";

$usermessage = "

Users Information
Name
$first_name $last_name

Email address
$email

Address
$address
$address2
$country
$city $state $zip

Phone Number
$phone

Qty
Item #";

foreach($vars as $idx => $v){
    if($_POST[$v]){
        $usermessage .= $idx . "\n" . $v . "\n";
    }
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";    

mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders,$headers);
}
```